# change text of label with image

Tags: image, wordpress, radiobuttonlist

It's possible change text of label with image? For example, #unaestrella have text "UnaEstrella" and i want clear text (or simply add image with padding or similar) and show an image from http://www.domain.com/images/unaestrella.png. It's this possible?

```
<ul class="radio_list">
    <li>
        <label for="unaestrella">
            <input id="unaestrella" type="radio" value="unaestrella" name="topics"/>
            UnaEstrella
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="dosestrellas">
            <input id="dosestrellas" type="radio" value="dosestrellas" name="topics"/>
            DosEstrellas
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can solve this with css:

```
ul.radio_list li label[for=unaestrella] {position:relative !important;float:left !important;line-height:25px !important;background-image:url(images/unaestrella.png);background-position:top left;background-repeat:no-repeat !important; width:100% !important;color:transparent !important;}
```

But it's possible with jQuery for delete text?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible but use a `class` for the `label`, because `#unaestrella` is the `id` that you have already used for the `input` and an `ID` must be unique, one `ID` must be assigned to only one element.

**CSS:**

```
.unaestrella{
    background : url('https://m.dominos.co.uk/m/iphone/assets/img/common/icon-single-small.png') no-repeat right;
    padding: 0 25px 0 0;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

**HTML;**

```
<label class="unaestrella" for="unaestrella">
    <input id="unaestrella" type="radio" value="unaestrella" name="topics" />
</label>
```

[**EXAMPLE.**](http://jsfiddle.net/WKYXT/)

Comment: thanks, only one problem, html is generated for a plugin. I found a posible solution: ul.radio_list li label[for=unaestrella] {position:relative !important;float:left !important;line-height:25px !important;background-image:url(images/unaestrella.png);background-position:top left;background-repeat:no-repeat !important; width:100% !important;color:transparent !important;} check here: http://www.buscatuspa.com/?post_type=post&topics=cincoestrellas

Comment: So, what's the problem ?

Comment: It's possible with jQuery for delete text?

Comment: Possible with `jQuery`, what do you want ?

Comment: delete text, not invisible for possibles errors in different browsers

Comment: Sorry! didn't get what you said.

Answer (score 1):

Add an `<img/>` element into your `<label/>` like this :

**In html** (http://jsfiddle.net/kyjey/)

```
<ul class="radio_list">

    <li>
        <input id="unaestrella" type="radio" value="unaestrella" name="topics"/>
        <label for="unaestrella">
            <img src="http://www.buscatuspa.com/wp-content/themes/Avada/images/unaestrella.png"/>
        </label>
    </li>

</ul>
```

**Edit to fit author requirement using jQuery** (http://jsfiddle.net/kyjey/2/)

```
$(function() {
    $('#unaestrella').next('label').empty().append('<img src="http://www.buscatuspa.com/wp-content/themes/Avada/images/unaestrella.png"/>');
})
```

Comment: thanks, only one problem, html is generated for a plugin. I found a posible solution: ul.radio_list li label[for=unaestrella] {position:relative !important;float:left !important;line-height:25px !important;background-image:url(images/unaestrella.png);background-position:top left;background-repeat:no-repeat !important; width:100% !important;color:transparent !important;} check here: http://www.buscatuspa.com/?post_type=post&topics=cincoestrellas

Comment: It's possible with jQuery for delete text?

Comment: See the jquery version if it fit your need